# Concept for Checking Static Member Privacy

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a `C++20` concept, intended to allow a CRTP interface to prevent the templated type from exposing a static member publicly:

```cpp
template< typename T >
concept BuildInaccessible = !requires
{
    T::build ( Ent {} );
};
```

I then use it like this:

```
static_assert ( BuildInaccessible< T >, "... must declare ... as a non-public static member" );
```

---

- With `MSVC 17.4.1` the constraint works perfectly.
- With `Clang 15`, the constraint seems to succeed even if the member is protected.
- With `GCC 12`, it also seems to succeed when it should fail.

Am I trying to do something non-standard, or do `Clang` and `GCC` not support this in these versions?

---

With `MSVC`, the static assert succeeds with the first class, and fails with the second:

```
struct SomePrefab : CRTP::Prefab< SomePrefab >
{
protected:

    static void build ( Ent target );

};
```

```
struct SomePrefab : CRTP::Prefab< SomePrefab >
{
public:
    
    static void build ( Ent target );
    
};
```

Whereas `GCC` and `Clang` always succeed at finding the member, making the protected member still fail the static assert.

Comment: "*the constraint works perfectly.*" What does that mean? The constraint doesn't do what you want it to. So what is MSVC doing? Where is your `static_assert`? "*the constraint seems to succeed even if the member is protected.*" Again, give an example of this code.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have added more context

Comment: You never said where your `static_assert` was.

Comment: If you want to ask whether any of the compilers is not behaving standard-conform, then please show a complete [mre]. You can also link it in https://godbolt.org, but it should at least be possible to copy-paste it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concepts are completely blind to accessibility (public/private). They are always public and therefore can only access things that are publicly accessible. They therefore cannot check to see if something is declared non-publicly. `BuildInaccessible<T>` will be just as `true` for a class `T` which has *no* declaration of a `build` member function as for one which declares it private.

Also, it's not a good idea to be this controlling over a conceptualized interface. If a user wants to declare it publicly for whatever reason, that's on them.

Comment: I see. What threw me off was that this approach worked with MSVC and not the others.